# Exibir mensagem conforme condição em query

Tags: sql, sql-server

Estou fazendo a diferença entre datas, quando a coluna `designacao_circuito` são iguais e a diferença (dias) entre a `dt_hr_fecom`  é <= 10, eu preciso que na coluna  `Reinc_10_Dias` escreva `Reincidente =<10 dias`, mas no primeiro registro e não no segundo.

Fiz o seguinte comando :

```
select 
        BASE_RREIP.designacao_circuito,
        BASE_RREIP.num_rec,
        BASE_RREIP.dt_abertura_rec,
        BASE_RREIP.dt_hr_abertura,
        BASE_RREIP.[dt_rec_fechamento_tecnico],
        BASE_RREIP.[dt_hr_fetec],
        BASE_RREIP.dt_hr_fecom,
        BASE_RREIP.rreip,
        UDS.[GERENCIA OPERACIONAL SUB] AS GERENCIATECNICASUB,
        BASE_RREIP.centro_funcional_local_anor,
        BASE_RREIP.UDS_Ofensor,
        BASE_RREIP.Piramide,
        BASE_RREIP.Tipo_RECs,
        BASE_RREIP.nome_causa_anor_rec,
        BASE_RREIP.nome_guerra,     
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION BY designacao_circuito ORDER BY designacao_circuito,dt_hr_fecom asc) as qtde,  ----- Numerando a quantidade vezes que se repete a Designação do Circuito

        (designacao_circuito + '-' + cast(row_number() over (partition by designacao_circuito order by dt_hr_abertura) as varchar)) as circuito_RREIP, ---- CONCAT da Designação com o Campo acima

         case when datediff(day,lag(dt_hr_fecom) over (partition by designacao_circuito order by dt_hr_fecom asc),dt_hr_fecom) <= 10 
                 then  'Reincidente =<10 dias' else 'Ñ reincidente =<10 dias' end  as 'Reinc_10_Dias', ----- INFORMA SE É REINCIDENTE OU NÃO        

        MONTH(dt_hr_abertura) as mês_ABERT,
        MONTH(dt_hr_fecom) as mês_FECOM 

 from  BASE_RREIP  LEFT JOIN UDS
                    ON BASE_RREIP.UDS_Ofensor = UDS.UDS
```

O resultado foi:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Diferente do print acima, a informação " Reincidente =<10 dias" está aparecendo no segundo registro, eu preciso que apareça sempre no registro anterior.

Comment: Mostre a `query` completa, por favor

Comment: Pronto, coloquei a query completa.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- O valor 'N reincidente =< 10' no primeiro registro é tido como o padrão do **LAG**, pois não vai ter ninguem anteriormente pra ele fazer a comparação, então vai printar o valord de 'else';
- Quanto as demais tuplas, será que não tem outro registro com esse mesmo valor de designacao_circuito? Caso tenha, provavelmente ele seja <= 10 da data **dt_hr_fecom**, e por isso esteja printando 'Reincidente =< 10 dias'...

Comment: Valeu Denis, um amigo deu a dica de usar LEAD no lugas LAG e aparentemente deu certo.  case when  datediff (day,dt_hr_fecom,lead(dt_hr_fecom) over (partition by designacao_circuito order by dt_hr_fecom)) <= 10 
        then 'Reincidente =<10 dias' 
        else 'Ñ reincidente =<10 dias' 
end as 'Reinc_10_Dias'case when 
    datediff
        (day,
         dt_hr_fecom,
         lead(dt_hr_fecom) over (partition by designacao_circuito order by dt_hr_fecom)) <= 10 
        then 'Reincidente =<10 dias' 
        else 'Ñ reincidente =<10 dias' 
end as 'Reinc_10_Dias'